# AS3 - Format for adding data to an array that feeds a datagrid?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, datagrid

I have a datagrid connected to an array.  If I hard code data into the array as such `var data1:Array = [{Name:"Joe Smith"}];`, the data displays properly.  However, I need to add the data dynamically via an input textfield and an add button.  Here's the bare bones of what I have:

```
public var grid1:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
public var i1:Number = 0;
var data1:Array = [];

public function Datagrid() {
    addBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addFun);
        grid1.move(20,120);
        grid1.setSize(760, 660);
        grid1.columns = ["Member"];
        grid1.dataProvider = new DataProvider(data1);
    }

public function addFun($e:MouseEvent):void{
        data1[i1] = [];
//this is the line I need help with - how do I format this so that the 
//datagrid can read it from the array as proper input?
        data1[i1][0] = "{Member:"+addNameTxt.text"}";
        i1++;
        grid1.dataProvider = new DataProvider(data1);
        trace(data1); // returns "{Member:Joe Smith}, but nothing appears on the datagrid

    }
}

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data1` array should be one dimension.
Instead of `data1[i1][0] =` use `data1[i1] =`.

This is not correct:

```
"{Member:" + addNameTxt.text + "}";
```

It's a String. It should be an Object:

```
{Member: addNameTxt.text};
```

Your code should looks like this:

```
function addFun($e: MouseEvent): void
{
    data1[i1] = {Member:addNameTxt.text};
    i1++;
    grid1.dataProvider = new DataProvider(data1);
}
```